# Eclipse, save project on main and backup folders

Tags: eclipse

I am using eclipse to develop a php project, I was wondering if there is a way that on "save" eclipse saves the project on two diferent folders, I want to use my google drive folder as my backup destination and also have my project on my working folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. Eclipse doesn't have any function for saving duplicates. However, there are plugins available to make it integrate nicely with Git, SVN, or other revision control systems for proper code backup (assuming you regularly push the commits to a remote repository).

You can also use a synced Google Drive folder as your workspace, and then everything will be synced with that drive.